# Cocos2d CCDrawNode fill with color

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d to ccdrawnode.DrawLineList method to create diamong shape. I am using the following code

```
   `var diamond = new CCDrawNode();
        diamond.DrawLineList(new CCV3F_C4B[] {
            new CCV3F_C4B(new CCPoint(0,height/2), fillColor),
            new CCV3F_C4B(new CCPoint(height/2,height), fillColor),
            new CCV3F_C4B(new CCPoint(height/2,height), fillColor),
            new CCV3F_C4B(new CCPoint(height,height/2), fillColor),
            new CCV3F_C4B(new CCPoint(height,height/2), fillColor),
            new CCV3F_C4B(new CCPoint(height/2,0), fillColor),
            new CCV3F_C4B(new CCPoint(height/2,0), fillColor),
            new CCV3F_C4B(new CCPoint(0,height/2), fillColor)
        });`
```

the diamond is drawn but the diamond is not filled with the color only the border is colored. How to fill the diamond shape with specific color in cocos2d